# How to render mapview as a circle?

Tags: android, android-mapview

Not to be confused with drawing a circle ON mapview. I'm trying to accomplish the following.

[image]

Should I, and how:
a) create the MapView as a circular view on another View?
b) render the MapView fullscreen and overlay another view with a transparent circle?

I'm not sure if either of these options are possible, I assume they are.  If it helps, as part of the user workflow the opaque area will have a couple of buttons but will eventually go away and the user will be left with the full screen map to interact with.

Thanks

Comment: Check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7559171/1321873

Comment: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/rounded-corners-mapview/

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I've found is by manipulating [CardView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) cornderRadius attribute and wrapping MapView inside it. Setting cardCornerRadius the half of l*ayout_width* and *layout_height* will create a circle View in which you can add MapView. If you don't want the shadow, set cardElevation to 0dp.

Here's the code example

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="100dp">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with canvas .See the following link for a rounded corner MapView:-

[http://blog.blundell-apps.com/rounded-corners-mapview/](http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/rounded-corners-mapview/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(MainMap.this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
    mc.animateTo( new GeoPoint(lat, lng));
    mc.setZoom(15);
    mapView.invalidate();
}
```

Dont forget to add overlay.enableMyLocation(); in onresume() and overlay.disableMyLocation(); in on pause

Instead of the above code if you want to draw circle around you point you can use following sample code:

```
Point screenPnts =new Point();
GeoPoint curr_geopoint = new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1E6),(int)(location.getLongitude()*1E6));
mapview.getProjection().toPixels(curr_geopoint, screenPnts);
canvas.drawCircle(screenPnts.x, screenPnts.y, 15, paint);
```