# MaskedViewIOS alternative for android?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mask

I am trying to find or figure out a way to create https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/maskedviewios.html that supports Android, with the main goal to mask image with another image outline (think twitter logo put over any photo where contents are only shown within twitter logo) This works fine in iOS, but there are no components I found that do similar job on Android. How would one go about creating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a masked view built in Android ([or build one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559171/is-it-possible-to-mask-a-view-in-android)) and the hook the native implementation to React Native.

Answer (score 1):

In a lot of cases, you use ClipPath from react native svg (shipped by default with expo) to do the job. Such example can be found here:
https://snack.expo.io/@wcandillon/soundcloud-player